# Passing argument 1 makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: objective-c

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSDictionary * ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"postilaatikko", @"mailbox", @"oppikirja", @"textbook", @"näppäimistö", @"keyboard", @"piano", @"piano", @"laskukone", @"calculator", @"manteli", @"almond", @"lumi", @"snow", @"vuori", @"mountain", @"aika", @"time", @"kynttilä", @"candle", nil];
    NSString * inputSentence;
    char cstring[451];
    NSArray * sentenceIntoWords;
    NSMutableString * translatedSentence;
    int i = 0;

    NSLog(@"Enter a sentence: \n");
    //scanf("%s", &cstring);
    gets (cstring);

    inputSentence = [NSString stringWithCString: cstring encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    sentenceIntoWords = [inputSentence componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

    for(i=0; i<[sentenceIntoWords count]; i++)
    {
        if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i] == nil])
        {
            translatedSentence = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex: i]];

        }
        else {
            translatedSentence= [ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey: [sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex: i]];
        }
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", translatedSentence);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is compare each word of a sentence entered by the user with the NSArray, replacing the key with the translated word when matching. Ok so I've changed it to this: 
if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            translatedSentence= [ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey: [sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex: i]];

```
    }
    else {
        translatedSentence = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex: i]];
            }
```

Now only the last word of the input sentence shows up, is there error in my logic?

Answer (score 2):

Bracket's in the wrong place. You want this:

```
if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i]] == nil)
```

What you have now is roughly equivalent to this:

```
BOOL isNil = [sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i]] == nil;
if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:isNil)
```

Obviously that's wrong, as `objectForKey` is (most likely) expecting an object pointer, not a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use primitive types with `objectForKey:`.

```
if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i] == nil])
```

`[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i] == nil` line will give you boolean output

so  this is wrong  `if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:boolean_value(yes/NO))`

you should do like this

```
if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:[sentenceIntoWords objectAtIndex:i]] == nil)
```

Comment: If objectForKey expects a pointer, how would if ([ProbablyInaccurateFinnishtoEnglshtranslation objectForKey:boolean_value(yes/NO)) make sense?

Comment: you should not use primitive value with objectForKey function.

Comment: ah makes sense now, i just misplaced the bracket.  I did what you said and now the last word of the input sentence is outputting.

Comment: use NSLog(@"%@", translatedSentence); inside for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Similar error it is showing in my program, i.e.passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

//Program to read the fasta sequence and randomize it!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int ac,char *av[])
{
  int i;
  int l1;
  FILE *file1;

  if ( ac < 2 ) return 0;
  file1= fopen( av[1] , "r" );    //"r" is a string and 'r' is a character
  char x;
  while(((x=fgetc(file1))!= EOF) && (x!='\n'));    //skip the header part
  while(((x=fgetc(file1))!= EOF) && (x!='>'))
    {
      if(isalpha(x))                             //reading all the alphabets after this(>) sign

        {
        printf("%c",x);

        }
    }

//To calculate the length of sequence

   l1=strlen(x);
   printf ("The sequence is %d characters long.\n",l1);

  //to Randomize all the characters present in a string(FASTA sequence)
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i=l1-1;i>0;i--)
   {
    char j = rand() % (i+1);
    char temp = j;  
     j = x;
     x = temp;

   }
  fclose(file1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error is in the strlen function